# Spark clean up shuffle spilled to disk

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, spark-streaming

I have a looping operation which generates some RDDs, does repartition, then a aggregatebykey operation.  After the loop runs onces, it computes a final RDD, which is cached and checkpointed, and also used as the initial RDD for the next loop.

These RDDs are quite large and generate lots of intermediate shuffle blocks before arriving a the final RDD for every iteration. I am compressing my shuffles and allowing shuffles to spill to disk.

I notice on my worker machines that my working directory where the shuffle files are stores are not being cleaned up. Thus eventually I run out of disk space. I was under the impression that if I checkpoint my RDD, it would remove all the intermediate shuffle blocks. However this seems not to be happening. Would anyone have any ideas on how I could clean out my shuffle blocks after every iteration of the loop, or why my shuffle blocks aren't being cleaned up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you cached the RDD to your memory/disk, as long as the spark context is alive, the RDD will be stored in your memory/disk.

In order to tell the driver it can remove the RDD from the memory/disk you need to use the `unpersist()` function.

> From the `java-doc`:
>
> ```
>  /**
>    * Mark the RDD as non-persistent, and remove all blocks for it from memory and disk.
>    *
>    * @param blocking Whether to block until all blocks are deleted.
>    * @return This RDD.
>    */
>   def unpersist(blocking: Boolean = true)
> ```

So you can use:

`rdd.unpersist()`

Comment: If I have a transformation train which involves a shuffle somewhere in the middle, and I've cached the final RDD from this transformation chain. Does calling unpersist() on the final RDD remove the upstream shuffle files?

Comment: Yes. Once you cached your RDD (transformations which returns an RDD does not have any difference than others), the moment this RDD will be unpersisted, all it related files (shuffled or not) will be removed from your worker's memory/disk.

Comment: shuffle != RDD cache

Answer (score 1):

depend on if you have dependency between those RDDs. For example:

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.<transformation>
val rdd3 = rdd2.<transformation>
...
```

this case, spark will remember the lineage, and there will always be a reference to the old RDD which makes it not be chosen to be cleaned up by spark driver(spark rdd clean up is down by gc on spark driver to recycle some rdd reference once they are not referred anymore).
so persist() won't work in this case, and the only way is to use `localCheckpoint()`. This is what I have done before and worked for me:

```
rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
          .localCheckpoint()
// do sth here and later
rdd.unpersist()
```

this makes spark truncate the lineage correctly and then you can safely unpersist() it without worrying about uncleaned reference.
please refer to spark doc see how to properly truncate execution plan lineage: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-checkpointing.html