# How can I clean up Spark shuffle files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with Spark (pyspark) to do big matrix-vector multiplications.

I have a loop that multiplies a matrix by a vector. The matrix is static, remaining the same inside the loop, but the vector gets updated.

Both matrix and vector are instances of a class defined by me that holds the data (in RDD) and has some utilitary methods.

The matrix was initially "dumped" in disk (from a saveAsTextFile operation) in coordinate format (i, j, value). The same is for the vector. Before the loop starts, I restore the matrix and the vector into two separated RDDs. Each multiplication is done by transforming their coordinates, followed by a join between the two RDDs and then by a reduceByKey. After the multiplication, I must check if the vector is unitary, so I need to do a reduce.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
# matrix and vector are RDDs restored from disk
for i in range(steps):
    # briefly, my multiplication is done with a join and reduceByKey operation
    vector = matrix.multiply(vector)
    # checking if the vector is unitary 
    if not vector.is_unitary():
        raise ValueError
```

In my first attempt, after the matrix is restored as a RDD, I called persist() and count() to materialize it in memory so the multiplications inside the loop would be faster. I've done the same for the vector to store it in memory too. The problem is: as the loop is being executed, the shuffle files are not being cleaned up (I suppose that happens because the RDDs are persisted), and, when the matrix is huge, I run out of disk space.

My second attempt was too unpersist the RDDs at the end of each iteration of the loop, so that the shuffle files could get cleaned up, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788507/spark-clean-up-shuffle-spilled-to-disk). Again, the problem is that the shuffle files are still not being cleaned up...

How can I avoid the shuffle files getting accumulated in disk?

I can provide more details if needed. I'm using MEMORY_AND_DISK StorageLevel and Spark 2.1.1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some clarification on how your code works? From the way you've described it, it does not seem like a very map/reduce friendly algorithm. What is your input data? What Spark operations are you applying  (e.g. `map`, `reduce`, etc.)?

Comment: I'd also add that (1) if you are doing one [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions), you do not need to worry about persisting or caching your RDD, and (2) similarly, there is no benefit from performing an unnecessary `count` before doing your desired computation - in fact, you are undoing the benefits of Spark's [lazy implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

Comment: @timchap thank you for your reply. I edited the question with more details. I know that if the RDD is marked as persisted, it will do so when the first action is executed, but I thought that calling unpersist() in each iteration, the shuffle files would get cleaned up, but they aren't... I would be nice if they got cleaned so I could use bigger matrices in my application

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/277/how-do-i-avoid-the-no-space-left-on-device-error.html